# Owin Middleware per controller in asp.net web API

Tags: asp.net-mvc, asp.net-web-api2, owin

I am using the following JWT middleware to authorize all controllers with a valid JWT and it works as expected. I need to enable client certificate based authorization on one of the controllers. I understand that i can create a new middleware and plug it into owin pipeline which validates client certificates.

How to decide which controller to use which middleware? As far as i know OWIN does not have any knowledge of any controller. Please suggest

```
public void ConfigureAuth(IAppBuilder app)
    {
         TextEncodings.Base64Url.Decode("IxrAjDoa2FqElO7IhrSrUJELhUckePEPVpaePlS_Xaw");

        var issuer = System.Configuration.ConfigurationManager.AppSettings["issuer"].ToString();
        var audience = System.Configuration.ConfigurationManager.AppSettings["ClientID"].ToString();
        var secret = TextEncodings.Base64Url.Decode(System.Configuration.ConfigurationManager.AppSettings["ClientSecret"].ToString());
        // Api controllers with an [Authorize] attribute will be validated with JWT
        app.UseJwtBearerAuthentication(
            new JwtBearerAuthenticationOptions
            {
                AuthenticationMode = AuthenticationMode.Active,
                AllowedAudiences = new[] { audience },
                IssuerSecurityTokenProviders = new IIssuerSecurityTokenProvider[]
                {
                    new SymmetricKeyIssuerSecurityTokenProvider(issuer, secret),

                }                   
            });

    }
```

Answer (score 0):

Owin "knows" which controller to authorise because of the [Authorise] tag on top of it.

Why don't you do the same for the other system? Create another tag which then fires up the other authentication system? It's the easiest way to keep a clean system working.

You can more than likely use the owin source code to get some inspiration and se exactly how things are done.